# Getting Excel to recognize non-standard date format

Tags: excel, date

I am pasting data from a web source that includes a date column. I need to be able to sort it  by date, but can not get Excel to recognize the columns as dates (it is sorting alphabetically instead).

Here is an example of the date format I have and the result I get when I try to sort it:

```
Aug-27 14
Aug-28 14
Aug-29 14
Nov-03 14
Nov-04 14
Nov-05 14
Nov-06 14
Nov-07 14
Oct-01 14
Oct-02 14
Oct-03 14
```

I am using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: please give more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the column and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to get the `Find & Replace` dialog. Use *<space>14* for the `Find what:` where *<space>* is an actual space character and *,<space>2014* for the `Replace with:`. Turn off *Match entire cell contents* within `Options` and click `Replace All`. The dates should transform into actual dates.

Make sure that that column is set to the *General* number format before attempting the replacement operation.

Comment: I did the search and replace but it is still not recognizing the output as a date and is only sorting alphabetically. Any ideas?

Comment: @gobi5 - My example may not have been perfectly clear. For the replacement text use either *<comma><space>2014* or *-2014*. The latter may be better given the original format but both work for me. Remember that the column should be formatted as *General* and not *Text*. If the replacement is not working then it is possible that you have *non-breaking spaces* instead of regular spaces. In that case use `Alt+0160` on the numpad to generate a non-breaking space.